# Get product version via terminal when building cmake project

Tags: build, cmake, version

Is there a way to get product version when building the project via cmake from terminal. In the CMakeLists.txt I have declared:

```
project(sayProject VERSION "1.0")
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: There is [PROJECT_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_VERSION.html) variable contained version of the current project. You may print value of this variable with `message` command, as usual.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I need to do it from terminal.

Comment: Not sure what do you want: `message()` outputs message into the terminal.

Comment: Does it mean you want to specify the version from the command line? If so introduce a variable and set its value in the call to cmake. In your CMakeLists.txt `set(USER_PROVIDED_VERSION 1.0) project(sayProject VERSION ${USER_PROVIDED_VERSION})` and in terminal call `cmake -H. -Bbuildit -DUSER_PROVIDED_VERSION=2.0`. This will create a directory named buildit and output the results of the configuration step of your project to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read the setting of `PROJECT_VERSION` without actually running `cmake`, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333065/53538) will get you that.

Specifically, I use this script:

```bash
cmake --system-information |
  awk -F= '$1~/CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION:STATIC/{print$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear from the question, but this:

```
message("cmake version ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
```

should output the current version of cmake to the terminal

or this:

```
message("project version ${PROJECT_VERSION}")
```

should output the current version of the project.