# Access variable from boost build/b2/bjam from shell script

Tags: shell, variables, bjam, boost-build, b2

I would like to be able to access the value of a variable which is computed inside a `jamroot` (or `jamfile`) from the shell.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474753/how-to-get-a-cmake-variable-from-the-command-line) for CMake.

Example `jamroot`:

```
MY_VARIABLE=42
```

Desired solution:

```
b2 --print-variable=MY_VARIABLE # running in a directory below the jamroot
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a satisfactory solution.

### First hackish solution: requires to modify the `jamroot`

by adding **at the end** (i.e. after variable is set):

```
import os ;
local B2_DISPLAY_VARIABLE_AND_EXIT = [ os.environ B2_DISPLAY_VARIABLE_AND_EXIT ] ;
if $(B2_DISPLAY_VARIABLE_AND_EXIT)-not-empty
{
    echo $($(B2_DISPLAY_VARIABLE_AND_EXIT)) ;
    exit ;
}
```

then run b2 with the environment variable set: `B2_DISPLAY_VARIABLE_AND_EXIT=MY_VARIABLE b2`

### Second hackish solution: requires to generate a custom file below the `jamroot`

`custom.jam` (generate it using the shell):

```
echo $(MY_VARIABLE) ;
exit ;
```

then run b2 with: `b2 -sJAMFILE=custom.jam` and then `rm custom.jam`

`JAMFILE` is a special [variable](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/tools/build/v1/variables.html) which for some reason is not mentioned in the [new doc](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/#jam.language.variables.builtins).

#### Remark

These solutions do not work if the variable is set from a `jamfile`. It may be possible to adapt the first solution using a custom target that would be called on the `jamfile`.